# Why drush "assume yes" -y option do not work for some commands

Tags: drush

Drush has global option `-y` (or `--yes`) which allow you not to type `y` on every promt during given command execution. (There is also `-n` or `--no` option to which following applies as well.)

This works perfectly when you run something like:

```
drush en i18n -y
```

The propblem arises, for example, when you trying to run `rsync` in that manner:

```
drush rsync @staging:sites/all/themes @production:sites/all/themes -y
```

Drush just don't get the `-y` option, and prompts you for a confirmation.

What is this and how to make use of `-y` option?

Comment: I would gladly hear downvoting reasoning, because I run into this [not so obvious] behaviour while scripting some automation, and it was, well, annoying enough.

Comment: `-n` is not the equivalent of `--no`, but rather `--no-interaction`: -n|--no-interaction see: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3082

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to pass all global options like `-y` or `-n` before drush command:

```
drush -y rsync @staging:sites/all/themes @production:sites/all/themes
```

This allows you to pass options to a shell command run with drush without getting in conflict with drush options:

```
drush [global options] command [command options]
```

This will pass `[global options]` to `drush`, and `[command options]` to a shell `command`.

Take a habit of passing `-y` and other global options right after you type `drush`.

Run `drush topic docs-strict-options` to get a help on that case.

Comment: This is a subtle difference, yet an important one when invoking commands. Thanks!